# Is internally .matrixWorld is used?

Tags: three.js

I have two functions which difference is using clone of originObj.matrixWorld to multiply with 'transform' argument.
the first one does not work but second one does.
as far as I know the 'matrix' and 'matrixWorld' properties of object3d are newly calculated in every frame, more specifically in renderer.render().
So I thought that assigning arbitrary matrix to .matrix or .matrixWorld is worthless, cause it will be overwrited in rederer.render().
If my thought is right, following two functions are working well either.
But only second one does work.
What is misunderstanding I am?

```
applyTransform(originObj, target, transform) {
    const newTransform = originObj.matrixWorld.multiply(transform);
        // decompose newTransformMatrix as position, rotation and scale
    const position = new THREE.Vector3();
    const quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
    const scale = new THREE.Vector3();
    newTransform.decompose(position, quaternion, scale);

    target.position.copy(position);
    target.quaternion.copy(quaternion);
    target.scale.copy(scale);
}



applyTransform(originObj, target, transform) {
    const newTransform = originObj.matrixWorld.clone().multiply(transform);
        // decompose newTransformMatrix as position, rotation and scale
    const position = new THREE.Vector3();
    const quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
    const scale = new THREE.Vector3();
    newTransform.decompose(position, quaternion, scale);

    target.position.copy(position);
    target.quaternion.copy(quaternion);
    target.scale.copy(scale);
}
```

I'm using threejs r90

Comment: Matrix worlds aren't necessarily automatically updated, as `camera.updateMatrixWorld()` needs to be called manually for example...

Comment: Thanks. I have more question not related this problem. Is not Object3d.matrix also automatically updated?

Comment: Hey friend hold on a minute. Reffering in this(https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Object3D.matrixAutoUpdate), it says matrix and mateixWorld are calculated in every frame, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a build-in function to apply a matrix to an object. The `Object3D.applyMatrix` method does exactly the same what your second function is doing.

> Applies the matrix transform to the object and updates the object's position, rotation and scale.

```
applyMatrix: function ( matrix ) {

    this.matrix.multiplyMatrices( matrix, this.matrix );

    this.matrix.decompose( this.position, this.quaternion, this.scale );

}
```

So, just call:

```
target.applyMatrix(originObj.matrixWorld);
```

**EDIT:** Oh, I forgot the transform;

```
var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4().multiplyMatrices(originObj.matrixWorld, transform);
target.applyMatrix(matrix);
```

Comment: Nope. My intention is setting the result of multiplying objOrigin.matrixWorld by some static transform matrix as matrix of target. The target should not multiply by originObj.matrix. so my function is not using target's matrix

Comment: Yeah, I recognized it in the moment when I hit the button to post the answer. So I updated it. But probably, it's not answering your question "why it's only working with a clone of `matrixWorld`" anyway.

Comment: Anyway your edition is also not for me. Seeing applyMatrix, it multiplies this.matrix by matrix in arguments. But I do not want multiplingy target matrix by transform matrix!